# Change one of the gradient colors for all objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have multiple objects that have the same gradient color. The gradient has two color points each. Is it possible to change one of the gradient colors to transparent for all of the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all your objects that have the same Gradient Fill. This can be done by selecting one object then going to Select> Same> Fill Color.

[image]

Then in the Gradient Panel (Window> Gradient) select one of the Gradient stop colors (the color filled circles below the gradient slider bar) and change it's Opacity to 0.

[image]